# What are the useful utility classes in java?

Tags: java, utility

There are some utility classes which can be useful in day to day development.

I know couple of such utility classes as below.

1. [Word Utils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html)
2. [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Both of these are basically from Apache commons library. Are there any other libraries or any such utility classes?

Comment: Why down vote?The reason I asked such question is that there are times when u need some small utility and sometimes you don't know if it already exist. Like may be you are using the commons library but you don't know if it has WordUtils. So one ends up searching for this on google or write one himself. Hence the questions :-(

Comment: A little broad! Just it seems that ppl could answer this question forever without conclusion.  All the commons stuff could potentially be useful, bvut so could almost any open source library depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think FileUtils & NumberUtils useful.Hope helps.